# Parallel.Invoke - Exception handling

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

My code runs 4 function to fill in information (Using Invoke) to a class such as:

```
class Person
{
    int Age;
    string name;
    long ID;
    bool isVegeterian

    public static Person GetPerson(int LocalID)
    {
        Person person;
        Parallel.Invoke(() => {GetAgeFromWebServiceX(person)}, 
                        () => {GetNameFromWebServiceY(person)},
                        () => {GetIDFromWebServiceZ(person)},
                        () => 
                        {
                           // connect to my database and get information if vegeterian (using LocalID)
                           ....
                           if (!person.isVegetrian)
                               return null
                           ....
                        });
     }
}
```

My question is: I can not return null if he's not a vegeterian, but I want to able to stop all threads, stop processing and just return null. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 8):

To exit the `Parallel.Invoke` as early as possible you'd have to do three things:

1. Schedule the action that detects whether you want to exit early as the first action. It's then scheduled sooner (maybe as first, but that's not guaranteed) so you'll know sooner whether you want to exit.
2. Throw an exception when you detect the error and catch an `AggregateException` as Jon's answer indicates.
3. Use cancellation tokens. However, this only makes sense if you have an opportunity to check their [`IsCancellationRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx) property.

Your code would then look as follows:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    Parallel.Invoke(
        new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = cts.Token },
        () =>
        {
            if (!person.IsVegetarian)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                throw new PersonIsNotVegetarianException();
            }
        },
        () => { GetAgeFromWebServiceX(person, cts.Token) }, 
        () => { GetNameFromWebServiceY(person, cts.Token) },
        () => { GetIDFromWebServiceZ(person, cts.Token) }
    );
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    var cause = e.InnerExceptions[0];
    // Check if cause is a PersonIsNotVegetarianException.
}
```

However, as I said, cancellation tokens only make sense if you can check them. So there should be an opportunity inside `GetAgeFromWebServiceX` to check the cancellation token and exit early, otherwise, passing tokens to these methods doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can throw an exception from your action, catch `AggregateException` in `GetPerson` (i.e. put a try/catch block around `Parallel.Invoke`), check for it being the right kind of exception, and return null.

That fulfils everything *except* stopping all the threads. I think it's unlikely that you'll easily be able to stop *already running tasks* unless you start getting into cancellation tokens. You could stop *further* tasks from executing by keeping a `boolean` value to indicate whether any of the tasks so far has failed, and make each task check that before starting... it's somewhat ugly, but it will work.

I suspect that using "full" tasks instead of `Parallel.Invoke` would make all of this more elegant though.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you need to load your `Person` from the database first anyway?  As it is your code calls the Web services with a null.

If your logic really is sequential, do it sequentially and only do in parallel what makes sense.