# ”Exception unhandled by user code“ when using Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I got an exception here:

> MyException was unhandled by user code

In fact I have tried this, but

What is the problem and how to resolve it? What I want to achieve is get the exception be catch by the try catch surrounded the parallel.All. Now, it does not aware of that try catch, and prompt me the exception is unhandled by user code. Noted that I require the `TestParallel1` method to throw exception, as this is the simplified format of the program I have. Given an exception, I wish to stop all other threads immediately. Furthermore I wish the exception propagate outside the parallel.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Action> act = new List<Action>
                      {
                         ()=>TestParallel1(),
                         () => TestParallel1()
                      };

                Parallel.Invoke(act.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)  // note the 's' in InnerExceptions
                {
                    //do something with 'e'
                }
                //do something
            }
        }

        public class MyException : Exception
        {
        }

        public static void TestParallel1()
        {
            throw new MyException();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Stacking the handlers like that won't work but you should not get an 'unhandled' this way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have edited again the code with your comments, it still does not work

Comment: Test carefully and describe what happens in detail. This should _not_ produce the unhandled exception error. Run without debugging to avoid confusion.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, I have run the code provided, screenshot provided, if you need more detail let me know.

Comment: Run it without the debugger (Ctrl+F5), or hit Continue (F5) a few times. You will get to the foreach loop.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hmm..but I need the debugger for development, to get rid of that windows is a better way to go.

Comment: i think the problem here is the `Parallel` because AFAIK it will Invoke your stuff on a separate thread so this may results in this behavior if you doesn't use `Parallel` it shouldn't occur

Comment: @WiiMaxx yea, I knew this...but I need the parallel.

Comment: The question is shifting. When you need to _stop all other threads_ then `Parallel.Invoke()` just isn't the right tool. And _immediately_ is not on the menu anyway.

Comment: @HenkHolterman but in this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724232/parallel-invoke-exception-handling, they are throwing the exception within the parallel.Invoke, if successfully, it should end all the threads within parallel.All. We can of course rethrow the exception catch by aggregateexception to achieve the propagate effect.

Comment: 1) There is no `Parallel.All()`. 2) Nobody on that other page has said that `Invoke()` will stop all threads.

Comment: @HenkHolterman 1)Sorry for the Typo, its Parallel.Invoke 2) What you mean is after catching the aggregate action, other threads in Parallel.Invoke will keep going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Catch this Exception and still use Parallel you could do this:

```
        List<Action> act = new List<Action> { () => TestParallel1(), 
                                              () => TestParallel1() };

        Parallel.ForEach(act, a =>{
            try
            {
                a.Invoke();
            }
            catch (MyException ae)
            {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

---

### EDIT

Maybe something like this could do the trick if events and delegates are ok for you 
i'm aware that this code could be look better but it will show you the idea so i hope it will help you :)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<MyThread> threads = new List<MyThread>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        var thread1 = new MyThread();
        thread1.A = () => TestParallel1();
        thread1.RaisError += RaisError;

        var thread2 = new MyThread();
        thread2.A = () => TestParallel1();


        threads.Add(thread1);
        threads.Add(thread2);

        Parallel.ForEach(threads, t => { t.Start(); });
    }

    public void RaisError()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(threads, t => { t.Stop(); });
    }

    public static void TestParallel1()
    {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}

public class MyException:Exception{}


public class MyThread
{
    public Action A { get; set; }
    public delegate void Raiser();
    public event Raiser RaisError;

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            A.Invoke();
        }
        catch (MyException me)
        {
            RaisError();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // do some stop
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 2

you may could also do this but you should read the [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461721/1993545)(from Scott Chamberlain) first

```
        List<Action> act = new List<Action> { () => TestParallel1(), 
                                          () => TestParallel1() };

        Parallel.ForEach(act, (a, state) =>
        {
            try
            {
                a.Invoke();
            }
            catch (MyException ae)
            {
                state.Stop();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, In fact I have tried this, but what I wish to achieve is given an exception, it stops all other threads immediately, using this method will only stop one thread. Furthermore I wish the exception propagate outside the parallel.

Comment: oh ok , i will see what i can do in this case :)

Comment: @william007 see my edit maybe this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the "unhandled by user code" in the debugger because you have "**Just my code**" setting turned on (and the original exception isn't technically being handled by your code, but rather being handled by the framework's code).

Turn off "Just my code", and you'll get a different experience.

Note, this is just debugging experience--it doesn't have any effect on the regular program flow.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Parallel members will *always* throw an Aggregate exception. You are catching the wrong type.

The changes you need:

```
//catch(MyException e)
catch (AggregateException ae)
{       

   foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)  // note the 's' in InnerExceptions
   {
        //do something with 'e'
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's won't help, edit my question, same exception unhandled problem persist.